# Is there a command to require WSO2-Carbon to check all config files for errors before a service restart?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I made several modifications to my WSO2IS config files and wanted to see if there was a pre-built command to require Identity Server to run a self-check on all available config files for errors before performing a service restart and potentially breaking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such a functionality in the existing WSO2 products. Maybe you can create a GitHub issue for that as a feature request :)